# The Flutter Daemon has terminated in VScode

Tags: flutter, flutter-apk

I'm learning app development using flutter. I've setup my mobile as physical device which worked fine but now whenever I open my project in VScode, I get a notification saying "The Flutter Daemon has terminated". VScode does not detect my device and I am now unable to run my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9sYJ.png)

Searched this problem but I can't understand those instructions so I'm posting this.

Comment: Please share the log for more information.

Comment: Did you press "Reload"?

Comment: @swedishcheef Yes, and it tries to reload and gives the same error again

Comment: @tk_tanz The log is too long so I can't paste it in this comment. How to do that?

Comment: @tk_tanz maybe this could help - This is the last line of the log: [8:20:10 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] <== [{"event":"daemon.logMessage","params":{"level":"error","message":"Unable to run \"adb\", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: C:\\Users\\SRS CONSTRUCTIONS\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe"}}]

Comment: check your Android studio installation, it seems that flutter is not able to find the android SDK. also check the environment variables if you have the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT present